# Making sudo not ask for password

Tags: command-line, sudo, password

I know this has probably been asked before, but I just installed Ubuntu last night and all the replies I read I honestly couldn't understand anything :p

I need to make some changes, and all of them seem to use sudo. 
When I formatted the pc and installed Ubuntu, it asked me for a password and didn't give me a chance, to have no password. So I then went on and removed the password completely, when the pc was on and the installation was complete.

I then had to use sudo as I said for a couple things, but it asked for a password. I tried to put the old one, I tried to leave it blank, I also typed NOPASSWD, and other variations of that. Nothing worked. I have rebooted the pc also in between of that so for now I have no idea what to do.

Please help, it's really frustrating :(

Edit: I am not looking to reset or restore any password. All I want is to not have a password set at all, and to not be asked for one by sudo, when there is none.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the issue is losing the password? I haven't lost it I just removed it completely? Is this a bug?

Comment: I did remove the password. I went into the user profile/ account, and removed it completely. Now it says "none". Sudo is still asking for password though.

Answer (score 0):

From the title :

You can edit your `sudoers` file like:

```
sudo visudo
```

And add the following entry, replace `user` with your username, for example `gogo`:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Press `ESC` then `:wq` to save it. Then re-login.

However this is consider as a very bad security approach.
Note that each active non-root account needs to have a password.

Edit:

Abbreviation `sudo` means `super user do`. Certain binaries are executable only from privileged account - `root`. Normal user accounts can escalate this by configuring their account in the `sudoers` file.

If you are asking for restoring the password, refer to the mentioned links in the comments.

Comment: This pc is in our living room and will be used only by my parents (that are 100% irrelevant with technology, to watch movies. Therefore having a password is completely useless in this case, and most of the time annoying when I'm trying to do things quickly. 

I never asked for restoring any password I'm not sure why my post is marked this way. But I will try what you said a bit later and let you know how it went! Thanks

Comment: If then so - please follow the instructions from my answer.

Comment: Okay I will do that later and update this post thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I've read the question more closely sorry, before applying my suggestion, you will need to apply @Matteo S. answer first probably if you don't you know your `root` password as well. If need more help, let me know.

Comment: What is a root password and when was that set? The only password I set was the profile password, that I have removed.

Comment: @Gogo it is a password for the `root` account, and it was set during the installation, and after then you've been probably prompted for a password for your `user` account.  Update your question with those two commands: `grep "root\|user" /etc/passwd`  and `grep "root\|user" /etc/shadow` . Replace `user` with the username of your account.

Comment: For both of those it says no such file or directory.